# Existing text messages not showing up in Messages app on new MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, icloud, messages, sms

I have a mid-2017 MacBook Pro that I would like to use with the messages app.

I have successfully enabled text forwarding, and can now send texts to both iMessage users and SMS users.

However, my Messages app does not seem to be able to get any of the old messages I have sent from my iPhone.

It can send and receive messages, but cannot seem to sync text history across devices.

This includes both iMessages and SMS messages.

I have confirmed that my phone number is set to the default form of sending and receiving messages on both the Mac and iOS messages app by following the guide [here](http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/09/fix-imessage-syncing-between-mac-ios/)

How do I get it to sync?

Answer (score 1):

Messages don't backdate & sync.

Each keeps its own record of messages it sent & received & syncs to other listed devices it can communicate with at the time.

If, for instance you receive messages at your Mac whilst your phone is out of network coverage, they will not appear later on the phone; The messages will be considered to be delivered when any registered device accepts it, & it will not be retransmitted to the other device later.

Answer (score 0):

I think that storing iMessage in iCloud is a macOS HS/iOS 11/watchOS 4 feature. Currently in macOS Sierra/iOS 10/watchOS 3 only new messages will be forwarded to your Mac, or other new devices.

If you wish, you can try installing the beta and seeing if that helps. (I did, and it runs great on my late-2016 MacBook Pro 15".)

Comment: How stable is the beta?

Answer (score -1):

Try turning off all message forwarding on all apple devices (iPhone, mac, ipad...). Wait 10 minutes and then turn the message forwarding on again on all devices.